# How to get the current URL behind a proxy_pass?

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

I have a HTTP service running on a server http://255.255.255.255:8888/ which is served using [`proxy_pass`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) on http://foo.tld/bar/baz/:

```
server {
    server_name foo.tld;

    location /bar/baz/ {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;

        proxy_pass http://255.255.255.255:8888/;
    }
}
```

Now I am making a GET request to get http://foo.tld/bar/baz/:

```
curl http://foo.tld/bar/baz/
```

The HTTP service running on the 8888 port is a simple [Express](http://expressjs.com/) app.

```
app.get('/', (req) => {
    console.log('req.url', req.url);
    console.log('req.originalUrl', req.originalUrl);
});
```

I want to get the URL (or at least absolute path) of the URL being requested. However, using the above code `req.url` and `req.originalUrl` is `/` instead of `/bar/baz/`.

How do I get the real absolute path of the service?

Comment: you've set your location to /bar/baz, so the service at foo.tld is running at this level of directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing:

```
proxy_pass http://255.255.255.255:8888/;
```

To:

```
proxy_pass http://255.255.255.255:8888;
```

Note that the `/` was removed.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, @evan-lucas answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/36290054/368691) to the original question is correct. To quote the [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass):

> If proxy_pass is specified without a URI, the request URI is passed to
>   the server in the same form as sent by a client when the original
>   request is processed, or the full normalized request URI is passed
>   when processing the changed URI:

The problem with this approach is that it requires the app to know the base URL (`/bar/baz`). One way to do this is to pass it via a custom header. Question answered.

However, for the record, lets rollback and understand the original problem (I am sorry for the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)):

My original issue was that my app attempted to redirect to the base path of the app, i.e.

```
app.get('/test', (res) => {
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

With this setup, I was expecting GET request `//foo.tld/bar/baz/test` to get redirected to `//foo.tld/bar/baz/`. But because HTTP service is hosted behind a reverse proxy the result of the above is that user is redirected to `//foo.tld/`. I have attempted to solve the issue by finding out whats the absolute URL of the app and redirecting user to that URL, i.e. to `/bar/baz/`.

I didn't like that @evan-lucas solution requires to make the app aware of the base URL. Therefore, I have looked into how to rewrite the [`Location`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location) header. Turns out that nginx provides a directive for that: [`proxy_redirect`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect).

Now I can do:

```
location /bar/baz/ {
    proxy_pass http://255.255.255.255:8888/;
    proxy_redirect ~/(.*)$ /bar/baz/$1;

    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
}
```

Now `Location` header such as `Location: /quux` is rewritten to `/bar/baz/quux` and app itself does not need to be aware of the real URL.

Answer (score 0):

In the proxy header, set the following to your host

```
X-Forwarded-Host
```

Add a trusted proxy to the app:

```
app.set('trust proxy', 'your internal IP');
```

And use this to retrieve the url

```
req.originalUrl;
```

Comment: The host is correct. It is the path that is incorrect.

Comment: Updated the answer to an improved suggestion.

Comment: Answer is still talking about host as opposed to the path.

Comment: The aim is to make the app understand the original url before the proxy, so the solution passes it on, you can retrieve different parts of the data then. Updated.